# Complexity reductions to Hamiltonian Path?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, reductions, hamiltonian-paths

I am looking for a NP-hardness reduction from an arbitrary problem to the Hamiltonian Path problem such that the reduced no-instances of Hamiltonian path are "far" from having a Hamiltonian path.

Do you know such a reduction? Or does there exist a list of reductions to Hamiltonian Path somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by "'far' from having a Hamiltonian path"?

Answer (score 11):

For undirected graphs, you can build a graph $G$ for every constant $0<c<1$ from an $n$-variate CNF SAT instance $I$ such that

- $G$ has $N=\operatorname{poly}(n)$ vertices
- If $I$ is satisfiable, then $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle
- If $I$ is not satisfiable, then $G$ has no path of length $N-N^c$.

[Karger Motwani Ramkumar 1997](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=2819BBB1447F33A6A69B556B78508B5C?doi=10.1.1.52.8469)

For directed graphs, you can build a graph $G$ for every constant $0<c<1$ from an $n$-variate CNF SAT instance $I$ such that

- $G$ has $N=\operatorname{poly}(n)$ vertices
- If $I$ is satisfiable, then $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle
- If $I$ is not satisfiable, then $G$ has no path of length $N^{1-c}$.

[Björklund Husfeldt Khanna 2004](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.105.262)